# Writing and Reading Content from Array into csv

Tags: python, csv

Hi I am experiencing the following problem:

I am writing the following content from a list/array into a CSV file:

```
18 Aug 2015 12:00:08 AM CESTFrankfurtFRA:New Instruments available on XETRA - 1
18 Aug 2015 12:00:07 AM CESTFrankfurtFRA:Deletion of Instruments from XETRA - 1
18 Aug 2015 12:00:06 AM CESTFrankfurtFRA:New Instruments available on XETRA - 1
18 Aug 2015 12:00:05 AM CESTFrankfurtDIVIDEND/INTEREST INFORMATION --   4`
```

with the following function

```
def _writeInCSV(text):
    #print "Writing in CSV File"
    with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        #spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t',quotechar='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t',quotechar="\n")
        for n in range(len(text)):
            spamwriter.writerow([text[n]])
```

Now I want to read the content from the CSV file into an array and I get "[]" always on every item. So the output looks like this:

```
["['18 Aug 2015 12:00:08 AM CESTFrankfurtFRA:New Instruments available on XETRA - 18.08.2015-002']", "['18 Aug 2015 12:00:07 AM CESTFrankfurtFRA:Deletion of Instruments from XETRA - 18.08.2015-001']"]
```

For reading the CSV I am using the following code/funtion:

```
def _readInCSV(your_list):

    with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            your_list.append(str(row))
```

The problem is that I am trying to get these elements as string without the "[]" in the beginning and ends.

So I want an output like this:

```
['18 Aug 2015 12:00:08 AM CESTFrankfurtFRA:New Instruments available on XETRA - 18.08.2015-002', '18 Aug 2015 12:00:07 AM CESTFrankfurtFRA:Deletion of Instruments from XETRA - 18.08.2015-001']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you're telling it to: outputting the string representation of the entire row. A row is a list, and a list always includes list delimiters.

You don't want that at all. You have one element, which is already a string; you should grab that element and append it, without calling `str`.

```
for row in reader:
    your_list.append(row[0])
```

Also note that your original writing function is very un-Pythonic. You should never iterate through `len(range(something))`: the very ugliness of that should tell you that it's not the way to do things. Instead, just iterate through the thing.

```
for item in text:
    spamwriter.writerow([item])
```

Finally, you might consider that, since you are writing a single element per row and reading it back, CSV may not be the appropriate format. A simple text write and read would be easier.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.